# TCP SYN_SENT from LibreOffice Headless in Docker Container.

Tags: c#, docker, tcp, libreoffice

I'm trying to get LibreOffice to run in headless mode within a container so I can use it for document conversions on windows.

Running LibreOffice locally via:

`C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program>soffice.exe -accept="socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;" -nofirststartwizard -headless`

produces a running instance of LibreOffice listening on port 8100

`C:\Program Files\LibreOffice 5\program>netstat -nao|findstr -c:"8100"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8100         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       28168`

Using the [LibreOffice CLI](https://api.libreoffice.org/examples/examples.html#CLI_examples), I can then use C# to successfully connect to the running application to convert my documents.

This all works fine, but when I run the same version of LibreOffice from a windows container my program hangs on the connection step and never times out or errors. *See the C# code snippet below.*

**dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore

ADD https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/tdf/libreoffice/stable/5.4.4/win/x86_64/LibreOffice_5.4.4_Win_x64.msi .

RUN msiexec.exe /i LibreOffice_5.4.4_Win_x64.msi
RUN del LibreOffice_5.4.4_Win_x64.msi

EXPOSE 8100

ENTRYPOINT ["C:\\Program Files\\LibreOffice 5\\program\\soffice.exe"]
CMD ["-accept=\"socket,host=127.0.0.1,port=8100;urp;\"", "-headless", "-nofirststartwizard"]
```

**docker commands**

```
docker build -t libreoffice .
docker run -d -v C:\FileRepository:C:\FileRepository --name some-office -p 8100:8100 libreoffice
```

**C#**

```
var xLocalContext = uno.util.Bootstrap.defaultBootstrap_InitialComponentContext();

var xURLResolver = (XUnoUrlResolver)xLocalContext.getServiceManager()
    .createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.bridge.UnoUrlResolver", xLocalContext);

// m_ServiceConnString = uno:socket,host=localhost,port=8100;urp;StarOffice.ComponentContext
// C# never returns from this line and doesn't error when LibreOffice is running via container
// The only way to recover is to kill the process.
var xRemoteContext = (XComponentContext)xURLResolver.resolve(m_ServiceConnString); 

var xRemoteFactory = (XMultiServiceFactory)xRemoteContext.getServiceManager();
 return (XComponentLoader)xRemoteFactory.createInstance("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop");
```

Running netstat during a conversion without the container (local LibreOffice) shows:

```
>netstat -nao|findstr -c:"8100"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8100         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       28168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8100         127.0.0.1:57531        ESTABLISHED     28168
  TCP    127.0.0.1:57531        127.0.0.1:8100         ESTABLISHED     36208
```

Running netstat during a conversion with a container shows:

```
>netstat -nao|findstr -c:"8100"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8100         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       15924
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8100         127.0.0.1:58931        ESTABLISHED     15924
  TCP    127.0.0.1:58931        127.0.0.1:8100         ESTABLISHED     25124
  TCP    172.27.208.1:58932     172.27.216.35:8100     SYN_SENT        15924
```

Not being a networking person I have a feeling this is something to do with how the connection is being made to the container, `SYN_SENT` seems to mean that the connection was blocked, but I can't be sure. `SYN_SENT` status also only lasts for a few seconds. I'm brand new to docker so I could be doing something wrong with how I'm creating & running the container. Any help would be great!

**Environment**

- Windows 10
- Docker 17.12.0-ce-win47 (15139)
- LibreOffice 5.4.4.2
- Docker network to host `nat`.

**docker ps**

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                    CREATED             STATUS
      PORTS                    NAMES
a2ad9cc76d8b        libreoffice         "C:\\Program Files\\Li…"   45 hours ago        Up 22 minutes
      0.0.0.0:8100->8100/tcp   some-office
```

**docker inspect**

```
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.IPAddress }}" some-office
172.27.216.35 // can't telnet to this ip with 8100 or ping.

docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.Networks.nat.Gateway }}" some-office
172.27.208.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

Connecting to the container reveals that I can telnet to connect to LibreOffice in the container.

```
docker exec -ti some-office cmd

telnet 127.0.0.1 8100
e ? ?'com.sun.star.bridge.XProtocolPropertiesUrpProtocolProperties.UrpProtocol
PropertiesTidm???
```

However, attempting to telnet by the container's IP fails.

```
docker exec -ti some-office cmd

C:\>telnet 172.27.216.25 8100
Connecting To 172.27.216.25...Could not open connection to the host, on port 8100: Connect failed
```

I changed the LibreOffice port from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0.0 which allowed telnet to work within the container by the container's port as well as from the host via localhost:8100.

Change the dockerfile and rebuild

```
CMD ["-accept=\"socket,host=0.0.0.0,port=8100;urp;\"", "-headless", "-nofirststartwizard"]
```

Or create the container via:

```
docker run -d -v C:\FileRepository:C:\FileRepository --name some-office -p 8100:8100 libreoffice -accept=\"socket,host=0.0.0.0,port=8100;urp;\" -headless -nofirststartwizard
```

Resulting Dockerfile file for those interested:

https://github.com/SRSsoft/libreoffice